# In Ubuntu Linux: Pass the clipboard content as parameter to some application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard, parameters

Is there a tool which can pass the content of the clipboard as parameter to some application?

For example I would use it like this:

(1) In a text editor or whatever, for example I could highlight and copy the IP number "74.125.224.72", to the clipboard.

(2) Activate the tool I'm looking for; it should launch the URL
http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=74.125.224.72 in a browser.

Essentially, it would be something reminding of the chrome extension "send-me-this" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-me-this/kgadhdbaebgblhbgojbegdjhmemapfgc , but it should be available everywhere, I mean not just when I'm in a browser.

I am on Ubuntu 10.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way o do this would be to use [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip):

1. Install `xclip`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xclip
   ```
2. Add this line to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   alias geoip='xdg-open http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$(xclip -o)'
   ```
3. Select the IP, open a new terminal and run

   ```
   geoip
   ```

NOTES

That should open your default browser on the geoip page for that IP. This assumes you have `xdg-open` installed, if you don't, either install it (`sudo apt-get install xdg-utils`), or change `xdg-open` to `chrome` or `firefox` or whatever browser you use. Also, if you use this when the clipboard's content is not an IP it will launch he browser but won't be able to load the page.

You should also be aware that there is more than one clipboard available, so the above will work if you have *selected* an IP, not if you have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. To use it with the latter, you should instead do

```
alias geoip='xdg-open http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$(xclip -selection "clipboard" -o)'
```

For more information, see `man xclip`.

If you want to run it without a terminal, make a shortcut for the command

```
xdg-open http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$(xclip -o)'
```

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks! It works fine with the alias. However, I  have one problem which I managed to work around: I get an error if I put the code into the command field in a custom shortcut or launcher, for some reason the URL seems to be truncated to 'http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$(xclip' . If I place the code into a bash script and write the path to the script in the command field, then it works perfectly.

Comment: The was a typo in my comment. The URL is actually truncated to `http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=$(xclip`

Comment: @JakobVinther umm, still not sure I understand. Does it work for you or not? If you want to make a shortcut, you might need to quote the entire command. Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: It is all fine, the only strange thing is that it doesn't work with the code directly in the shortcut. I have tried quoting the whole thing with `"` as well as `'`, but none of them worked. The last part `-o)` is lost somehow. It doesn't matter, because I'm very happy with the solution you gave, and I have accepted it of course.